# Split in csv file using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, excel, csv

friends i have two CSV files i need to convert to spread sheet. It contains following data;

```
"xxx","yyy","97,234"
     .
     .
     .
```

and

```
abc,def,"23,475"
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

now what is the problem is i need to open this csv file and write each record it into another file.i've tried with split function as `split(,@lines)` this 'll split all coma separated values so fist file third record also split by two!.so i've tried another way `split(",@lines)` this method won't support second file!any method to handle this case using ***perl***

Comment: `split(,@lines)` and `split(",@lines)` is not even close to valid perl code. Joining the files does not require parsing csv, that is a job for `cat`: `cat file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Text::CSV to parse CSV files. A sample usage of Text::CSV is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
$\="\n";

open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv' or die $!;
my $csv=Text::CSV->new;
while(<$fh>){
        $csv->parse($_);
        my @fields=$csv->fields();
}
close $fh;
```

The array `@fields` contains all the individual columns of the csv file.

Comment: so the quotation are removed?

Comment: so you mean "xxx","yyy","97,234" looks like:xxx,yyy,97234 this look like  abc,def,23475 'm i right?

Comment: @Thiyagu ATR: I would run it with debug option (perl -d myscript.pl) to inspect how it handles this

Comment: @ThiyaguATR : yes, it removes the quotes in the individual columns...however, when you combine the fields using combine method, it reclaims the quotes..

Answer (score 2):

If you need to copy all records from your two CSV files into a third file then you don't need to split the data at all: just read and write the data at a record level.

If, for some reason that you haven't explained, you *do* need to split the data into fields, then you should do it using the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV) module. Trying to split CSV data using a regex is difficult to get right in general, and the module is tried and tested.

Comment: @ThiyaguATR I see now that you have the "excel" tag on your question. If your question is about how to convert csv to excel you should include that in your question. Otherwise it is hard for people to figure out. Although I think Microsoft Excel can import csv just fine.

Comment: If you need to convert this data to a spreadsheet then it is probably best to open the CSV files using your spreadsheet application.

Comment: @all:no I've plenty of csv files,i need to do this process by automation!using perl!actually I've complete 80% of the work,at the end I've noticed  this big probe!

Comment: Then the answer is to use Text::CSV as I have said

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you don't want the `"` included in the output:

```
my @values = $line =~ /\"?(\w+)\"?,\"?(\w+)\"?,\"?([\d,]+)\"?/
```

will remove any `"` and store the text/numbers in the array @values, which you can then print:

```
print join(";", @values) . "\n";
```

to have them printed with `;`as a separator. When I run the two lines from your question through that, I get this output:

```
$ ./testregexp.pl 
xxx;yyy;97,234
abc;def;23,475
```